# file name too long while building a go library

Tags: go

I am trying to build a -linkshared go library that includes different go Github projects. When I pass more than a certain amount of packages in the go install command it returns an error, **filename too long**.

`go install -linkshared -buildmode=shared github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/ github.com/labstack/echo/ github.com/urfave/negroni/ github.com/go-redis/redis/ github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis github.com/go-chi/chi/ github.com/gocql/gocql/ github.com/gorilla/mux/ github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/`

I tried changing the source code a bit, but it won't let me. It always returns a:

`go link -V=full: unexpected change:`
and then it exits.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: you should use go mod to include all modules

Comment: @JakubDóka Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think I'll be able to make use of go.mod in my case, as I want to build a shared library with all these packages, and that shared library will be used by another c library, which in turn wraps the functions present inside these go GitHub packages.